# How to specify timestamp along with date in postgresql

Tags: sql, timestamp, postgresql-9.3

I would like to specify a static timestamp along with dynamic date in postgresql

I am using now()-1 to get date. I am not sure how to specify static timestamp

The format should be 2015-06-12 20:45:00:00

Now I am using select now()-1 from dual to get previous date.

Comment: What do you mean "static timestamp"? A literal?

Comment: Does postgesql not have functions that allow you to format dates and times?

Comment: static meaning. Date will change everyday but time will remain static. that is 10:45 @Mureinik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty hard to be sure as you haven't really shown your inputs and outputs, but I'm *guessing* you want a *timestamp* with a *variable date part* and *fixed time part*.

If so, you probably want something like:

```
SELECT (current_date - INTERVAL '1' DAY) + INTERVAL '20:45:00';
```